# Amazon SES DKIM verified but doesn't remove via tag in gmail

Tags: email, amazon-ses, amazon-product-api, dkim

I am trying to remove "via amazonses.com" in emails received using gmail. I tried to search around but everyone says that once the DKIM is verified the issue will be resolved. However, in my case even after verifying of DKIM I am still seeing via amazonses.com

[image]

Following is a screenshot of the email received
[image]

Do I need to send any DKIM signature while sending the email too? Because I haven't dont any specific settings for DKIM apart from verifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, adding DKIM in the domain settings isn't enough. You need to do the same for the email address from which you intend to send emails. So once the domain DKIM is verified head to email section. Following instructions provided on the page and add DKIM signature for the specific email. Once you are done the 'via amazonses.com' will disappear.

I hope it helps all those who are having trouble removing 'via amazonses.com' even after verifying DKIM for their domain.

Comment: How to do that? How to add DKIM signature for specific Email ?